# Displaying a fits image with multiple channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, astropy, fits

[Here is my expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuSkR.png)

I downloaded a fits image with multiple channels from CASA. I tried to upload the image like I would a normal fits image, but it shows an error

> "Invalid dimensions for image data".

The image has a shape (1, 20, 250, 250).

Is there a way to display all the channels?

When I try the code I did below, it shows only one of the channels.

```py
file2 = "Downloads/PVDiagramtest2.fits"
image_data = fits.getdata(file2)

image_data = image_data[~np.isnan(image_data)]

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image_data[0,0,:,:])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Abstractly speaking, each channel is just another 2D image, so the question you should be asking first is exactly in what way you want to display all the channels?  Combined into some kind of false color image?  Stacked in an array of images, somehow?  You'd have to be ask yourself this question first.

Comment: I just put up a picture of the channel maps I generated through CASA. I want it to be displayed something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see all the images, you can loop through with subplots.  A toy example of how to plot multiple images together would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   

x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
z = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

for i in range(16):
    plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, c=z, marker=verts)
plt.show()
```

In your case, I think that may look something like this:

```
from astropy.io import fits
# import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   

file = "WFPC2u5780205r_c0fx.fits"


image_data = fits.getdata(file)

# image_data = image_data[~np.isnan(image_data)]


num_channels = 4
x_dim = 2
y_dim = 2
colors = ['rainbow', 'PuRd_r', 'gist_earth', 'coolwarm']
for i in range(num_channels):
    plt.subplot(x_dim, y_dim, i+1)
    plt.imshow(image_data[i,:,:], cmap=colors[i])
plt.show()
```

Of note, I commented out where you where bit-flipping on `np.isnan()` because it seems to be flattening the image array, and I don't see a rational for using this type of approach when it only seems to be introducing an issue.  However, perhaps with your data, it behaves as you like.

For this example, I used the first sample FITS file available from the [FITS Support Office](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_samples.html).  The image is 4 channel 200x200 pixels.  Other than making the 2x2 grid using subplots, I haven't formatted the image.  Here's the output image from this sample code:[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your input. I'm still running into this error "num must be 1 <= num <= 20, not 0". I think it's because the channel numbers start from 1 to 20, and there is no 0 channel. I tried an if and else statement, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try incrementing range from 1 then. I updated the code

Comment: This is the latest error I've run into "too many indices for array". The data has a lot of nan values, but I accounted for that using np.isnan.

Comment: If you can post a sample like `PVDiagramtest2.fits` it would be much easier to figure out exactly what will work.

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't seem to allow me to post files, and when I try changing the fits extension to png, it says the file is too large.

Comment: I updated with a sample fits file so you can give that a try.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike, it works now. The np.isnan gave a different shape which I never took into account.